# how to flip from bottom an iOS view with appcelerator

Tags: ios, view, translation, appcelerator, flip

I have an application which displays a view inside another view with appcelerator 5.1.2.

I want to animate the view to appear from bottom when opened, but could not figure out how to do it.

I have already done the exact opposite which is to make it disappear to bottom. Here is the code :

```
function closeViewFromBottom(animationView) {
    var newtop = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight + 20;
    animationView.animate({
        top:newtop,
        duration:1000,
        autoreverse: false
    }); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the start top value to platformHeight and then animate top to 0. Also set the height of that view to platformHeight. For iOS you can also set the outer-view clipMode to Titanium.UI.iOS.CLIP_MODE_ENABLED

*Edit:* full example

index.tss

```
"Window": {
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
}

"#view":{
    backgroundColor: "red",
    width:Ti.UI.FILL,
    height:Ti.UI.FILL,
}
```

index.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <Window >
        <View id="view"/>
        <Button id="btn" title="show view"/>
    </Window>    
</Alloy>
```

index.js

```
$.view.top = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight;

function openViewFromBottom(animationView) {
    animationView.top = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight;
    animationView.animate({
        top:0,
        duration:1000
    });
};

function onClickButton(e){
    openViewFromBottom($.view);
}
$.btn.addEventListener("click",onClickButton);
$.index.open();
```

Comment: it does not work, the view appears briefly a fraction of seconds at the bottom of the screen and seem to go down and fully disappear below bottom.

Comment: @mostaldev I think it would be helpful to have a little bit more context. Could you provide a fully (not) working sample? A window with the parent of `animationView` so that it is more easy to test and help you get this right?

Comment: @mostaldev could you please try to start at 'platformHeight - 1'. And do you have other TSS applied to the view?

Comment: I've added a working example (tested on Android only, no iOS device)